# Can you get/scrape emails from instagram accounts?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Someone is telling me that they can get all the email accounts associated to instagram accounts. Which would be a gold mind for marketing obviously.

They gave me my email associated to my email account as proof.

From my understanding, email addresses are hidden on instagram and this can not be done. But, i do not know how he got that email address as i use it ONLY for instagram.

I went and tried to do a password reset to see if they gave you the email when you request a pass and no it blocked out half my email address and i couldntmake it  out.

So, can you get emails attached to instagram accounts? i do not see how this could be done

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't. Instagram API does not provide it. And the "retrieve password" page and requests seems well done, so you don't have access to the e-mail (and you really should not).

This info below is the officially data response from Users endpoint.

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
        "bio": "This is my bio",
        "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
        "counts": {
            "media": 1320,
            "follows": 420,
            "followed_by": 3410
        }
}
```

If someone really knows your e-mail, I can imagine some options:

1) You use the same e-mail on Instagram and on another service that delivers e-mail (e.g. Facebook) and this guy has access to this service and had a lucky guess with you.

2) They googled you and discovered your main e-mail somewhere, and had a lucky guess.

3) They discovered a security vulnerability somewhere on Instagram code and now are exploring it. (but this is no good)

If I were you, I would create another account with a brand new e-mail and ask him again to "discover" this new one. If he can, the 3rd option is probably the right one. And if you do this, please share with us! :)