# Instagram user's contact e-mail?

Tags: ruby, email, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

Ruby on rails dev here.

This question has been asked before. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167140/can-you-get-scrape-emails-from-instagram-accounts), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58759376/how-do-i-access-an-instagram-users-contact-information) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53328319/how-can-i-scrape-business-email-contact-with-python). 
The problem is that they did not make the right question or the solution given was somewhat shallow.

I ´ll be as specific as I can.

**The Goal**

I want get the user´s contact e-mail and not the account e-mail. Two different things. :) 
Some users leave their email on the contact button. It´s public.

My goal is to make a software that can extract e-mails, but for now, only extracting one e-mail from one single account will be more than enough to have my MVP going.

here is an example below on how instagram let users share their e-mail.

[image]

**The Problem**
It only shows in app :( If it were to be shown on the browser as well, it would be a walk in the park. The contact button that has the e-mail and phone number does not show in the browser.

**The Good Part*
There is some solutions to it.

[This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsQgdUMYv9k) has a figured it out using the API, but I don´t quite understand how he did it. The downside is that all solution wants to sell you a product.

The focus of [this company](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yStuxV62XKQ&feature=emb_title) lies on extracting instagram e-mails and it seems legit.

Last but not least, [this dude](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSsSLFJ1FK0) is using appium to extract those juicy e-mails. The third won´t really work for me because it seems too messy. Having to use a android emulator will be my last resort.

Thanks for helping and happy new year.

Comment: Please include your attempted solution in the question body itself and any other code you are refereeing to as well. You should not expect people who are using their time to help you to have to dig around and visit multiple other pages to get the gist of your question. This also helps prevent link rot which makes questions and answers useless over time. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Instagram also has a public API that you should be using instead of a web scraper. If the data you are looking for is not available through the API you should NOT use a web scraper to try to circumvent it. Thats a violation of the TOS and you could be held liable.

Comment: Hey, Max thanks for the feedback. Still new to this, but I thought the more info I can give the better no? As for code, there is none yet, because that´s the very root of the question. Knowing if there is a proper way to do it.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior
and  "[Don’t use “click here” and other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)". More information is not necessarily better; Concise and clear questions are the goal. Adding artificial headings like "The Goal" and "The Problem" don't really help navigation unless you can supply links to each and have a table-of-contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set up [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) on your machine.
- Set up the certificates on your phone and use your machine as the gateway.
- Analyze the traffic.
- Reverse engineer the API (to log in and get info about user profiles) and then use it in your Ruby/Python/whatever code.

Comment: Since I´m such a noob did not know that was possible to reverse engineer an api. Will try that out. Thanks.

Comment: It's a private API that's used by the mobile app. Maybe there's an existing description/client library somewhere, you can try searching for that yourself.